# android tile game not outputting map

Tags: java, android

I am making a tile based game in Android Studio. I want the map to output circles (islands) if it loops past a 1, and the circle should be in the correct grid coordinates however when I run it nothing happens at all.

```
int gameBoard[][] = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int R = 0; R < 4; R++) {
            if (gameBoard[i][R] == 1) {
                Paint Blue = new Paint();
                Blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                canvas.drawCircle(i, R, 10, Blue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with color, you also need to set a few other things:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

or

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

It's possible that your onDraw method isn't being called. If adding the paint style doesn't fix your problem entirely, you should probably verify that onDraw is being called with a log at the beginning of the method.